# Javascript RegEx "invalid quantifier"

Tags: javascript, regex, quantifiers

```
var search = new RegExp("<span class=\"highlight\">(?<text>.*)</span>", "g");
```

Is there something wrong with the RegEx? Firebug just says "invalid quantifier". Thats it, no more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark quantifier is wrong there. You want to match and collect between the brackets `()`. Doing `(?` is wrong, if you want to match `(` you should escape the brackets.

`var search = new RegExp("<span class=\"highlight\">(<text>.*)</span>", "g");`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `(?<text>.*)` was supposed to be a named group, which isn't supported by JavaScript regexes.  The equivalent non-named group would be `(.*)`.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Yeah, it was. I used the non-named group instead.